# Integrity of gpg communication after sending the private key by email

Tags: public-key-encryption, private-key, gnupg

My collegue has sent me by email his gpg private key generated by:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor <id> > private_key.asc
```

instead of his gpg public key as (I supposed) recoverable by:

```
gpg --armor --output public_key.gpg --export
```

Is now his gpg key "corrupted", in the sense that having sent it by email its integrity is no more trusted?

Should he revoke that key?

Answer (score 1):

The worst case assumption is that someone listened to the mail and is right now trying to guess the passphrase chosen by your colleague. The safest (and imho correct) thing to do is to revoke the key and generate a new one.